# How to uninstall Avira antivirus from Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

I installed Avira on my Ubuntu now. These are the commands I used to install Avira:

```
wget http://dlpe.antivir.com/package/wks_avira/unix/en/pers/antivir_workstation-pers.tar.gz
tar xvzf antivir_workstation-pers.tar.gz
sudo ./antivir-workstation-pers-3.1.3.5-0/install
```

After installation I tried to open Avira by searching it in the computer, but its not found anywhere. Because of this I want to uninstall it. How to uninstall it ?

Comment: How did you search? With nautilus, or using command line tools?

Comment: @Tom: Why do you trust Avira when it is closed source? Avira probably can include malicious features. Don't you know that the people who make anti viruses are the same people who make viruses?

Comment: @Naveen Thanks for the information. Can you suggest me an antivirus software that can be trusted ?

Comment: I can recommend CalmAV for Ubuntu. You should carefully read this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Antivirus

Answer (score 1):

From Official Avira Antivirus `man`:

Uninstalling AntiVir.

You can use the uninstall script, located in the temporary AntiVir directory, to remove
Avira AntiVir Server/ Professional. The syntax is:

```
uninstall [--product=productname] [--inf=inf-file] [--force]
[--version] [--help]
```

where productname is **Guard**.
Open the AntiVir directory:

```
cd /usr/lib/AntiVir/guard
```

Type:

```
./uninstall --product=Guard
```

The script starts uninstalling the product, asking you step by step, if you want to
keep backups for the license file, for the configuration files and logfiles; it can also
remove the cronjobs you made for Guard and Scanner.

Answer the questions with `y` or `n` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Avira AntiVir Server/ Professional is removed from your system.

Comment: After this - "./uninstall --product=Guard" , it says "The script  must be run as root". What to do now ?

Comment: did you type `sudo` then? That's obvious, because you're making changes to the system and you gotta do that as `sudo` user (root,admin) not as a basic user.

Comment: I selected not to install the guard for the moment, so there is no folder /guard at my installation.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an older version without uninstall script, delete these files as root:

```
sudo su
rm /etc/avserver.conf /etc/avguard.conf /etc/avupdater.conf*
rm -Rf /usr/lib/AntiVir/
rm /usr/bin/antivir*
```